# Generate 'Time To Live' param with every URL in an MVC- Spring based application?

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, csrf, session-timeout

In an HTML response returned to a client, how can I append a param-value to each HTTP URL? I want to append these param-value to all URLs generated in my application and want to code this at one location.

Comment: Please post a link to the blog article so we can see how your question relates to his suggestion.

Comment: What is TTL? Is that how long you want the session to stay active or is it something internal to your application?

Comment: I tried re-phrasing my question. Thanks.